# Transconsistency operators and degrees of logical explosivity?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, paraconsistency, principle-of-non-contradiction, inconsistency

So I noticed in an article I was reading that they talked about *consistency* and/or *inconsistency* or otherwise *transconsistency* operators. I don't recall the details, but they sound like propositional operators, though presumably on conjunctions?

Let an *x*-inconsistent logic be a logic that can "tolerate" *x*-many contradictions. Now, the tolerance is not reached and then the logic is explosive; I don't want to commit to the explosion problem for finite logics as such. Let's say that the *x* is for how many contradictions the logic can handle before becoming *paracomplete*, or instead (congruently, although I don't know if equivalently...) that the logic's abstract/overarching degree of *relevance* decreases. **I don't know the steps I'd have to interject to thwart the manifestation of explosions as long as I as have the standard model of disjunction in play, except the step I will propose now.**

A paracomplete logic representing a default in the disjunction elimination dynamics of the system, let's say that the infinite disjunctions made possible by the alephs over their successor-many ordertypes would bring the proto-explosion principle of disjunction into play, and that if the disjunction occurred in an omega-inconsistent logic, because of the possibility of rearranging all the elements of the set of contradictions to form successor-many more contradictions (embedded into the higher cardinal), and so on and on down the line, the result would be a truly explosive logic.

**My question is:** is it possible to define a logic of paraconsistency, as an operator theory, with something like an *x*-inconsistency parameter, relevant to degrees of relevance and explosivity? My main interest in trying to develop this idea is twofold: (A) to balance a problem of logical pluralism in my methodology; (B) to deepen/expand upon the standard model of large cardinals in model-theoretic terms, esp. modulo consistency/transcompleteness issues.

**Addendum.** *The mathematical reasoning:* for a finite set of sentences, if you have that many positive sentences, and your set must be finite, you then have no negative sentences. At any rate, you can only have half as many sentences consisting in true contradictions as there are finitely-many sentences available in local logical space. In a world of only 16 specific facts, only 8 can form pairs of true (or "tolerable") contradictions. However, once we have reached *omega*, we can have infinitely many positive sentences all paired with their negations for (0, 1, 2, ...) on the one hand and (0, -1, -2, ...) on the other, or *omega *+* omega*. And then however it will not be that we can infer an explosion to a finite extent, but an infinite one; so whereas from the 8 subcoherent sentences we might infer an explosion of degree *n*, yet from the infinitary subcoherence structure can can infer an infinite degree of an explosion, much closer in spirit (and letter!) to the idea of "inferring everything at once."